# Как заставить работать Swiper.js в модальном окне Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, modal, swiper.js

Есть карусель с картинками, которую надо выводить в модальном окне. Однако, выводится из неё только первый слайд, остальные слайды пустые. Код такой:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="itemModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="itemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content bg-white">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-primary" id="itemModalLabel">Заголовок</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close text-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body pt-0 pb-0">
          <div class="swiper itemSwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper mb-3">
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/img1.jpg"></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/img2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/img3.jpg"></div>
                ...
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/imgN.jpg"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И яваскрипт свайпера

```
    var itemswiper = new Swiper(".itemSwiper", {
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      spaceBetween: 30,             
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
        mousewheel: true,
    });
```

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем выводить swiper.js-ом? Не лучше ли использовать всеми любимый fancybox?

Comment: А вообще думаю вам инициализировать swiper нужно при открытии модального окна, так как вызов модального окна тоже является вызовом функции, а значит должен быть порядок выполнения, сначала вызов окна и потом только вызов swiper.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи пытался воткнуть код свайпера в $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { ... тут ... }); но все равно никаких изменений. Свайпер работает, слайды крутятся, но картинка отображается только в первом слайде.

Comment: Странно, если swiper работает, тогда дело не в js. Там получается просто в модальном окне вам нужно обозначить ширину окна, в которой находится swiper. Видать те другие картинки просто на весь экран растянулись. Дело в css 100%

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи неа, заменяю все картинки в слайдах на текст - так же показывается текст только с первого слайда. Нажимаю на стрелочку, он прокручивается, и дальше - пустота.

Comment: Я об этом и говорю, текст и картинки никуда не делись, этого не может быть просто, так как это обычный HTML. У вас ширина swiper больше модального окна и когда вы крутите её, вторая картинка где-то находится за рамками модального окна, которое скрывает все элементы из-за overflow: hidden; Поэтому вы думаете, что ничего не отображается, а на самом деле просто за рамками модального окна находится. <div class="swiper itemSwiper"> посмотрите у вас по идее должен выходить за рамки модального окна по ширине